# J2ME multiple form/screen pattern

Tags: java, design-patterns, java-me, mobile

I can't seem to find any examples on the web on J2ME apps with multiple "forms" or screens. What is the best pattern to handle multiple screens in a MIDlet and keep the memory consumption low?

Here's a sample display structure (any can be a form or plain canvas with custom items),

Main Menu
   - Sync
   - Settings
      - Item
         - Another one
         - ...
            - ...
   - List
      - Item
         - Edit
            - Some other display

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Lightweight UI Toolkit](https://lwuit.dev.java.net/). It has different UI elements and UI patterns including the one you have listed. See if this helps you out.